# mix marketing model_base sales

Tags: model, mixed-models

https://github.com/robbenyam/mmm_stan

The "Readme" said: predict base sales (X_ctrl) as an input variable to MMM, this represents the baseline sales trend without any marketing activities.

the predict base sales derived from base sales model , and this model is based on the relationship between "sales" and "control varibles", however, data of "sales" are real data which influenced by both of "control varibles" and "media varibles".

Is it reasonable to say that predict base sales represents the baseline without any marketing activities?

Thanks